# Understanding $\langle u, v\rangle$ notation with regard to a Projection Matrix

Tags: notation, vectors

I'm trying to read and understand Wolfram Alpha's page on a Projection Matrix:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProjectionMatrix.html

Can someone help me understand the meaning of the $\langle\cdot \,,\,\cdot\rangle$ notation seen below? The brackets with two, comma separated, terms is new to me (or old and long since forgotten).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle u,v \rangle$ denotes the [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html) of the vectors $u,v$.